# Why this code compiles?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a code.

```
class A
{
public:
    int foo(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
};

int foo(int i)
{
    return i;
}

int (A::*ptrFoo)(int) = NULL;
int (*_foo)(int) = NULL;

int  main()
{
    ptrFoo = &A::foo; 
    _foo = foo;

    (*_foo)++++++++++++++(10);   //This dont compile...

    A a;
    (a.*ptrFoo)+++++++++++++++++(10);  //This compiles ????

}
```

please tell me what it is ?? a undefined behavior or what ??? I compiled it in VS2008.Strangely the last line of code compiles successfully.

Comment: `++++++++++++++` is seven and a half post-increment operators. Presumably the compiler is getting caught up on the half.

Comment: You compiled it as both C and C++? Or why did you include both tags?

Comment: i compiled it in c++(VS2008).i will remove "C"tag

Comment: @todda.speot.is: No. generally any arithmetic including `++` and the "half increment!" `+` on function/member function pointers are undefined.

Comment: Why not post a simpler example? E.g is the number of `+` relevant to the question at all?

Answer (score 2):

Neither expression should compile:  in C++, you cannot perform arithmetic on a pointer to a function or member function, or on a function type or member function.  The two expressions in your program attempt to perform arithmetic on a function and on a member function, respectively.

If your compiler accepts the second expression, it is due to a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

First note that **pointer to functions** are different with **pointer to member functions**.

Your first example is a pointer to an ordinary function. It contains the real memory address of the function. When you dereference it (`(*_foo)`) you get the function itself, and arithmetic operations including `++` on a function (function pointer) are meaningless.

The second one is another story, pointers to member functions of classes do not carry the address of the function in memory. Actually how compiler manages member functions is implementation-specific. A pointer to a member function may contain some address or maybe some compiler-specific information. Arithmetic on this type is also meaningless.

Therefore we don't know what the value of `(a.*ptrFoo)` ever is, but in your case MSVC2008 managed to compiler it, either because of a bug or by design.

By the way, GCC does not compile any of the two statements and threw errors on both.

The above is true whether you put even number of `+`'s or odd numbers; we are doing arithmetic anyway. (If there are an odd number of `+`'s then there is no function call, as in your second example you are incrementing the function 8 times then the last remaining `+` adds 10 to the result. Again, this doesn't matter: we are trying to change a function/member function pointer.)

Comment: "how compiler manages member functions is implementation-specific"  The implementation of nonmember functions is also an implementation detail.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: You're right, but every ordinary function has an explicit address in the memory, no? But the 'address' of a member function is not something we know; each compiler has its own paradigms on implementing classes.